# How to dismiss a popover with a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller, popover

I have an app which is divided in four views, when I tap a view the app shows a popover and that popover has a navigation controller. I can navigate between view and the data is shows correctly. But when I am in the last view and I tap a row, the popover don't dismiss (I want in didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

How could do it?

I tried in this way, I created a method that dismiss the popover and I call this method en didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but did not works.

This is the method in the main ViewController

```
-(IBAction)mostrarTabla:(id)sender
{
    // Popover that shows the table
    UIPopoverController *popover;

    // RootViewController is the first view

    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    // With a nav bar
    UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [rootViewController release];

    // Popover customitation
    navBar.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(20.0f, 20.0f);
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navBar];
    [navBar release];
    popover.delegate = self;
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 832.0f);

    // PopOver is shows in the view 1
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f) inView:_view1 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

I create a method in this View Controller

```
-(void)hidePopover
{
    [self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

And in the last view I used the method but did not works

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController *grafica = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    self.indicadorId = [[self.arrayId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];

    DataIndicador *datos =[[DataIndicador alloc] init];

    datos.idIndicador = self.indicadorId;

    [datos release];


    [grafica hidePopover];
}
```

In the last view I want that the popover returns to its view and shows the data (a chart)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The grafica instant of the ViewController is not the same as the whatever instant of VieController that was originally presented the popover.